# Is it okay to mark image.crossOrigin as "anonymous" even when it is not?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

When using cross origin urls for images with the canvas api, if the image is cross origin I am getting a tainted canvas exception. [MDN Allowing cross-origin use of images and canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

Changing `crossOrigin="anonymous"` fixes the issue; however, is it okay to always do that? Or should I check the url first to make sure that it really is crossOrigin before setting it to anonymous?

e.g.

```js
function isCrossOriginURL(url) {
  const { location } = window;
  const parts = url.match(/^(\w+:)\/\/([^:/?#]*):?(\d*)/i);

  return (
    parts !== null &&
    (parts[1] !== location.protocol ||
      parts[2] !== location.hostname ||
      parts[3] !== location.port)
  );
}

console.log(isCrossOriginURL("https://stacksnippets.net"))
console.log(isCrossOriginURL("https://google.com"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is not OK to always set `crossorigin=anonymous`.

The `crossorigin` attribute is a statement that you want to do something to the image which requires permission using CORS.

If the server doesn't grant permission using CORS then you won't be able to do things with the image that *normally* don't require permission … such as displaying the image at all.

```html
<img src="https://placem.at/places?h=100&w=100" alt="No CORS needed">

<img src="https://placem.at/places?h=100&w=100" crossorigin=anonymous alt="Requires CORS">
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `crossorigin` for requests sent to the same origin is allowed. In the general case, I would not recommend to do so because:

- it is useless
- it could be misleading as credentials *are* included anyway

but it will not break your code to do so.